# Improper Placement of NaNs Using Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

I have three Pandas dataframes, which I am concatenating to a master dataframe and then pivoting the table for use with Seaborn heatmaps.

All dataframes have the exact same dimensions (1 row x 11 columns), however the third dataframe included in the concatenation contains 9 NaNs at the end to ensure its the same length as the first two (##,##,nan,nan...).

The code used to achieve that is as follows:

`hrdp_heat = np.hstack((hrdps, np.zeros(9) + np.nan))`

The code for the table pivot is as follows:

`hmap_data2 = pd.pivot_table(heatmap_data, values='highs', index=['model'], columns=['dates'])`

The pivot executes successfully, however the values associated with the third dataframe are improperly shuffled, such that the two values that lead the row are shifted (see the output below):

`60.0 61.0 54.0 51.0 51.0 59.0 49.0 55.0 53.0 62.0 51.0
58.0 63.0 55.0 51.0 51.0 59.0 50.0 55.0 54.0 62.0 50.0
nan 62.0 nan nan nan nan nan 58.0 nan nan nan`

How do I execute the table join so the order of the values remains intact (62.0, 58.0, nan, nan,...)?

Comment: Can add code to this question that generates the three datasets and then what your expected output would look like with regards to this generated data?

Comment: Sure, the expected result looks identical to the output on the bottom, however with the 62.0 and 58.0 leading the rest of the NaNs. The two lines above the one in question are fine, and do not need any adjustment

Comment: `heatmap_gfsmos = pd.DataFrame({'model':'gfsmos', 'highs':gfsmos, 'dates':objects_10})
heatmap_ekdmos = pd.DataFrame({'model':'ekdmos', 'highs':ekdmos, 'dates':objects_10})
heatmap_hrdps = pd.DataFrame({'model':'hrdps', 'highs':hrdp_heat, 'dates':objects_10})
heatmap_data = pd.concat([heatmap_gfsmos, heatmap_ekdmos, heatmap_hrdps])
hmap_data2 = pd.pivot_table(heatmap_data, values='highs', index=['model'], columns=['dates'])`

Comment: @TornadoEric, put the code in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Uh... Can you create some mock data?   Since I don't know what gfsmos and ekmos nor hrdp_heat are.